# Force download file that's not placed on the server

Tags: php, file, pdf

I'm trying to force download a pdf file that I'm generating. I don't need the pdf file to be actually saved on the server.

So when I generate my pdf file, I get the file content. I then encode it with base64. Now the problem is that I need to force download it. I've looked all over the web, but I haven't found any search results that tells me how to do this without the file actually being placed on the site.

I've tried the following code:

```
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"invoice.pdf\""); 
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($pdffile));
readfile(base64_decode($pdffile));
```

But, it's giving me a corrupt pdf file, (1 kb). The actual file should be around 50kb.

Any ideas, as to what I can try?

Comment: Probably the file length encoded is different from decoded, right? Did you tried removing 2nd and 3rd line to see if it works?

Comment: That did not work, I tried with readfile($pdffile) as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

readfile trying to output content from file, but you have only data string. Try this instead:

```
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"invoice.pdf\""); 
echo base64_decode($pdffile);
```

I also suggest rename $pdffile to $pdfcontent for even better clarification.

Comment: that worked :3 thanks, it makes a lot of sense ^^ I'll accept it as soon as I can